# toString not getting applied to mixture of numbers, characters and special symbols

Tags: javascript

I am trying below code:-

```js
var testrename = {
  check: function() {
    var str = 988,000 PTS;
    var test = str.toString().split(/[, ]/);
    console.log(test[0] + test[1]);
  }
}

testrename.check();
```

I want output as- 988000

I was trying it on node

Comment: Where is `temp` defined?

Comment: updated the quertion. I am getting 988,000 PTS as data inside variable.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you expect `"- 98000"` as result and not `"988000"`?

Comment: The code seems to work, your expectation is wrong.

Comment: What you you mean with `toString not getting applied`? `str` is already a string, so what should `toString` do in thsi case?

Comment: Now I'm confused. What is the question? To me it seems, that the code works as expected. Or was your problem really just the missing quotes around the string?

Answer (score -1):

Your `str` variable's assigned value needs to be quoted in order to assign a string value to it, and for it to be recognized as a string.

It looks like what you're trying to do is extract the integer value of a string, so return 988000 from the string "988,000 PTS", and you would use `parseInt(string)` for that.

Update: The comma will break the parseInt function and return a truncated number, (988 not 988000) so you can use the replace function with a regular expression to remove all non-numeric values from the string first.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
var testrename={
  check :function() {
    var str ="988,000 PTS";
    cleanStr = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
    var test = parseInt(cleanStr);
    console.log(test);
  }
} testrename.check();
```

Comment: You should not reference w3schools, they had inaccuracies and false informations in the past and still have. You should always specify the `radix` parameter, because the default that is use for `radix`  can change for different implementation and and js versions. This information is partially included in the link, but they should clearly suggest to always set `radix`.

Comment: This will not work `parseInt("988,000 PTS")` will result in `988` and not in `988000`, because  `[...]If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.[...]` [MDN: parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @t.niese - Good point - I've updated the example to use the string.replace function to strip non-numeric values from the string first and then pass to parseInt, and linked to MDN instead of w3schools